# GDB Emacs hangs after running any binary

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am trying to set up Emacs and GDB such that I can have the gdb-many-windows option running. However, m-x gdb hangs after running any binary, and Emacs starts consuming 100% CPU and becomes unresponsive.

I am running on:

- OS X 10.10.1.
- Emacs 25.0.50 (the one in Homebrew)
- GDB 7.8.1 (the one in Homebrew)
- My Emacs setup is here: https://github.com/ChrKroer/emacs-setup

Here's what happens:

I run some binary with m-x gdb and then 'gdb --i=mi [name of binary]'. Everything works fine, the correct windows set up and everything. I then give the command 'run' to GDB, and it runs the code correctly. But once the code finishes, Emacs becomes unresponsive and start consuming 100% CPU power. This happens even with a simple hello world program. I have tried giving various options like --annotate=3, --fullname etc.

If I instead run m-x gud-gdb, I can run the same binary just fine, gdb exits normally and I can continue using Emacs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is confirmed in my mac. What's more, emacs with the same configuration (actually no configuration at all) works well in my Linux machines. So it is a bug related to Mac OS X.

### Update:

- It seems that some modes/plugins in emacs which conflicts with "gdb". When I run it without loading anything in .emacs, it stops hanging emacs when gdb debug finished.
  I will try to track which mode causes such problems, and report it here.
- <s>It seems that many modes could lead to freezing emacs when gdb finishes debugging, e.g. "helm" and any modes using helm, "function-args" (which enables some features of helm in its source codes)</s>
- <s>To my configuration, dozens of modes enable, `helm` is the critical mode that cause `gdb` to freeze emacs when it reaches the end.</s>
- It's not due to `helm`, but due to `semantic-mode`, which might be enabled when you want to use `helm-semantic-or-imenu`.

### Conclusions:

It is caused by `semantic-mode`, which performs poorly in Mac OS X, even its basic functionality has bugs. Under Linux, it doesn't have any obvious issues, that's why `gdb` works in Linux. Search around your `.emacs` and make sure disable all `semantic-mode`, then it should work.

Note that, even though you disabled `semantic-mode` before run `gdb`, if `semantic-mode` is initially enabled, it will still freeze emacs. `semantic-mode` has be initially disabled.

Thanks to **thierryvolpiatto** for help in debugging:
https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1168#issuecomment-140132443

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for the answer! Maybe I will give this mode of editing/debugging another try :)